# How to pass through &str lifetime to Box<dyn Fn()>

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to do simple telegram bot. I have to response some answer for provided questions.

Problem is that I can't use borrowed parts of question (string) to pass through it to db save function.

I've cut my code as mush as possible:

```rust
pub enum Answer {
    DbCommand(Box<dyn Fn()>),
}

pub fn process(question: &str) -> Answer {
    let parts: Vec<&str> = question
        .split(" ")
        .collect();

    let channel = parts.get(1).unwrap();

    Answer::DbCommand(Box::new(|| {
        save_to_db(channel)
    }))
}

pub fn save_to_db(chan: &str) {
    // Saving to db
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=190c2eb1d8ae1760178b5e855bb2d510)

Output is:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `question`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:23
   |
5  |   pub fn process(question: &str) -> Answer {
   |                            ---- help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `question`: `&'static str`
...
12 |       Answer::DbCommand(Box::new(|| {
   |  _______________________^
13 | |         save_to_db(channel)
14 | |     }))
   | |______^ lifetime `'static` required
```

If I add some function lifetime, then I get error E0495. There's not much information on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` does not allocate anything, it only iterates over the initial string, keeping a reference to it. You need to own the string and move it into the closure:

```
pub enum Answer {
    DbCommand(Box<dyn Fn()>),
}

pub fn process(question: &str) -> Answer {
    let channel = question.split(" ").nth(1).unwrap().to_owned();

    Answer::DbCommand(Box::new(move || save_to_db(&channel)))
}

pub fn save_to_db(chan: &str) {
    // Saving to db
}
```

By the way, you do not need to collect anything in this case.

If you really don't want to allocate a string, you can make your struct generic over a lifetime, but I think that this would add an unneeded complexity.:

```
pub enum Answer<'a> {
    DbCommand(Box<dyn Fn() + 'a>),
}

pub fn process(question: &str) -> Answer {
    let channel = question.split(" ").nth(1).unwrap();

    Answer::DbCommand(Box::new(move || save_to_db(channel)))
}

pub fn save_to_db(chan: &str) {
    // Saving to db
}
```

That's because a trait object has an implicit `'static` lifetime by default.

Comment: Thank you for response. Your first example doesn't compile. I tried to change save_to_db(chan: &str) to String type, but then another error appeared. Another problem that in my real code i need to check if second, third... parts exists or match some string

Comment: @Sartor Sorry, that was due to an edit from someone else. It works now. `save_to_db` needs a `&str`, so `channel` must be borrowed.

Answer (score 0):

My final code looks like this:

```rust
pub enum Answer<'a> {
    Text(String),
    DbCommand(Box<dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error> + 'a>),
}

pub fn process(question: &str) -> Answer {
    let mut parts = question
        .split(" ")
        .map(str::trim)
        .filter(|s| !s.is_empty());

    let command = parts.next();

    match command {
        //...
        Some("/subscribe") => {
            match parts.next() {
                Some(channel) => {
                    Answer::DbCommand(Box::new(move || {
                        db::subscribe_to_channel(&channel)
                        //...
                    }))
                },
                None => Answer::Text("Provide channel name".into()),
            }
        },
        _ => Answer::Text("Invalid command.".into()),
    }
}
```